# Blurry text in chrome on < button> element related to css transform?

Tags: css, button, transform

I am using a menu that is animated using a transformation of an < svg> element with buttons on top of it. Strangely the text on the buttons is extremely blurred in chrome, while it is nice and crisp in all other browsers I have tested so far.

[image: crisp text in firefox]
[image: blurry text in chrome]]

The blurry text is not related to the < svg> element. (which was my first guess) If I remove it the text is still blurred. It seems to be related to the < button> element. Just displaying the text without it being in the < button> gives nice and crisp text in chrome.

This is the css currently assigned to the button element:

```
.grid figure button {
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
border: medium none;
background: #316BA8 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
color: #FFF;
opacity: 0;
transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) scale(0.25);
```

this is the transform that takes place on hover: (when the buttons with the blurry text come up)

```
.grid div:hover figure button {
opacity: 0.9;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) scale(1);
transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) scale(1);
}
```

I have found other posts relating blurry text in browsers (not always chrome) to css transformation but I haven't been able to find any answer that could have been applied to my problem. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: PS. Removing all transformation elements from the animation leads to crisp text - but then the entire menu does not work any more as intended. (Since I need to make the buttons zoom in or out.)

Answer (score 2):

It's the scaling (maybe even because it's combined with opacity 0.9) - try finding the sweet spot if you can or try checking if it works better with/without the hardware acceleration.

But there's not much more you can do about it because it's entirely done by a browser.

Comment: The button is scaled to 100% , that should be the most easy to render - no? I have tried changing it in margins of 10 or 5 and there is no difference in blurryness.

Comment: It could be a scale/opacity combination. What happens with `opacity: 1`? Can you create the live code in a snippet here or a fiddle?

Comment: I found a solution - the problem was not the scale() part, but the translate() parts. I have now removed all the translate() transformations and just reset the buttons to the left via a "margin-left:0px;" Working fine in Firefox and chrome. Will check other browers now. :)

Comment: Nice! Can you try if translates still work, but when you use pixels?  Because, percentages can cause browsers to go into subpixel rendering mode (imagine 50% of 111 pixels - what happens with that half a pixel?).

Comment: yes - translation using pixel values works too! :) nice
Of course all of this kind of sucks if I were going for responsive, but thankfully this menu has a fixed size anyhow.

Comment: Yeah, for responsiveness, you'd probably have to do something like using JS to make sure the parent element's resolution is divisible by 2 so that the 50% transition ends up on a rounded pixel value.